# React native: Android build fail "parseDebugLocalResources failed"

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I'm havind this error when i try to build my react native app with :

- npx react-native run-android

```
> Task :react-native-date-picker:parseDebugLocalResources FAILED
ReactNativeFirebase WARNING: NPM package '@react-native-firebase/storage' depends on '@react-native-firebase/app' v15.7.0 but found v14.12.0, this might cause build issues or runtime crashes.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
169 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 166 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-date-picker:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
   > '/Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/react-native-date-picker/android/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/._drawable' is not a directory

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 55s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-date-picker:parseDebugLocalResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
   > '/Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/react-native-date-picker/android/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/._drawable' is not a directory

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 55s

    at makeError (/Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Volumes/Untitled/project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Project versions:

- React-native: 0.68.2

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        kotlinVersion = "1.6.21"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // New line
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1')
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21" // <- add this line

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // New line
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }

        exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

I tried clearing cach rebuild update gradle version, and delete node-modules and reinstall but didn't work checked my android API version '31' but didn't find a problem.

Comment: Same here! Any solution?